# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Exceptions

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

Past few days Getting **[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)** .I know this type of questions already asked on #SO . I tried .

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Code

```
String[] Child_DOB = "KUSHAGRA (SON)-07/05/94AANVI (DAUGHTER)-12/06/00 VARENYA (SON) - 26/12/05";
        ArrayList<String> children_List = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> Length_List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String Children_Details_str = "";

        int i = 0;
        while (i < Child_DOB.length) {
            String name_dob = Child_DOB[i] + "  " + Child_DOB[i + 1];//this line
            if (i > 3)
                Children_Details_str = Children_Details_str + "\n" + name_dob;
            else
                Children_Details_str = Children_Details_str + name_dob + "  ";
            children_List.add(name_dob);
            Length_List.add(Child_DOB[i].length());
            Length_List.add(Child_DOB[i + 1].length());
            i = i + 2;
        }
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: before accessing you can check using if condition

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. But you can check like this: `while ( (i + 1) < Child_DOB.length) { .. }`

Comment: String[ ] Child_DOB : incompatible type, it should be String. Split String and make String[ ].

Comment: you have only one stringelements in "String[] Child_DOB" so it will have only  Child_DOB[0] but not have elemts Child_DOB[i+1]  so its throwing index out of exception

Comment: @Janak the value of `Child_DOB ` is hard coded

Comment: @void   provide the value you are use.

Comment: index i+1 doesn't exists

Comment: Pretty clear why you get the exception, you're accessing an element at index **1** while your array only contains **ONE** item on index **0**, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why getting down votes ??

Comment: Because the exception is clear, you even know on which line it is and you're not explaining what you're trying to achieve. I don't really see the point of posting for help when you're not even explaining what you're trying to achieve. We don't know what your objective is by saying `my objective`.

Comment: `String[] Child_DOB = "KUSHAGRA (SON)-07/05/94AANVI (DAUGHTER)-12/06/00 VARENYA (SON) - 26/12/05";` this isn't valid Java, your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of line as you pointed out:

```
String name_dob = Child_DOB[i] + "  " + Child_DOB[i + 1];//this line
```

Say you have only one element in your `Child_DOB` array, you would enter your while loop, and with `i = 0` try to access `i+1` i.e. 1st element. Array starts with 0th index and hence accessing element at index 1 would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. To avoid this one option would be:

```
while (i < Child_DOB.length - 1) {//go until second last element
```

This would work if your array has even number of elements. If you have odd number of elements then you would miss the last name (which should be fine as per your logic.)

if you really dont want to miss the last element, you could do something like:

```
if ((Child_DOB.length & 0X1) == 1) {
    Length_List.add(Child_DOB[Child_DOB.length - 1].length());
    //append to Children_Details_str.. better use StringBuilder here
}
```

Comment: I will try this .

Answer (score 2):

Change your `while` loop `condition` as:

```
 while (i < Child_DOB.length - 1)
```

**Explanation:**

For example, `Child_DOB.length` is `5` and `i` value is `4`, In your code:

```
    int i = 4;
    while (i < 5) {
        String name_dob = Child_DOB[4] + "  " + Child_DOB[4 + 1];
```

Here `Child_DOB[5]` causes  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because array `index` start from 0 and your `Child_DOB` index's are `[0 1 2 3 4]`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: @void what is the current status of your issue? Try my answer to solve it..

Answer (score 1):

There is only one String in `CHILD_DOB`.
In your while statement you typed `Child_DOB[i + 1]`;
which accesses `CHILD_DOB[1]` but there is only one item in `CHILD_DOB` which is `CHILD_DOB[0]`
Try this

```
String[] Child_DOB = new String[] {"KUSHAGRA",
 "(SON)-07/05/94AANVI", "(DAUGHTER)-12/06/00", "VARENYA", "(SON)", "-", "26/12/05"};
```

Which I think would fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one element in **Child_DOB** so **Child_DOB.length**=1, and inside while loop you are trying to access 2nd element **Child_DOB[i + 1]** in first iteration itself... So you are getting exception...
Can you tell exactly what output you want??

Answer (score 1):

Use-

```
while (i < Child_DOB.length - 1)
```

Instead of -

```
while (i < Child_DOB.length)
```